# Flutter GetX state isn't changing

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-getx

Hello everyone i need help with getx state management,
I have a boolean value loading by default it's false after that it changes after loading data

```
     RxBool loading=false.obs;

  List<String> texts =<String>[].obs;

  getData()async {
    print('loadimg :' + loading.value.toString());

    loading=true.obs;    print('loadimg :' + loading.value.toString());

    var result = await http.get(Uri.parse(main_url));
    print(result.statusCode.toString());
    var data = json.decode(result.body);
    data.forEach((element) => texts.add(element["title"]));
    print(data);
    loading=false.obs;
    print('loadimg :' + loading.value.toString());
  }
```

And i need to check this value if it's true i show a widget otherwise i show another widget
but when i call this boolean value into the second screen it always true

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  PostController controller = Get.put(PostController());
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    controller.getData();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App'),),
      body:controller.loading.isTrue? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()): ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return Card(child: ListTile(title: Text(controller.texts[index],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 24),)));
      },itemCount: controller.texts.length,),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to wrap scaffold body content with an `Obx` widget or similar ones that listens to observable changes and rebuild the ui.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App'),
      ),
      body: Obx(() => controller.loading.isTrue
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                  controller.texts[index],
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24),
                )));
              },
              itemCount: controller.texts.length,
            )),
    );
  }
```

Also, on your controller you don't have to re-assign `loading` variable everytime. Just do it like this `loading.value = true;`